# R: Subset a dataframe based on group and different conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Consider a data frame:

```
data = data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
              b=c("apples", "oranges", "apples", "apples", "apples", "oranges"),
              c=c(12, 22, 22, 45, 67, 28), 
              d=c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday"),
              out = c(12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22),
              rate = c(-0.01, -0.02, 0.03, -0.04, 0.07, 0.06))
```

I want to subset the data frame to keep values when rate is negative when fruit is apples and rate is positive when fruit is orange. i.e. my desired output is

```
data = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),
              b=c("apples", "apples", "oranges"),
              c=c(12, 45, 28), 
              d=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday"),
              out = c(12, 18, 22),
              rate = c(-0.01, -0.04, 0.06))
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do with `dplyr`. However, you can easily do this with `subset`

```
data = data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
              b=c("apples", "oranges", "apples", "apples", "apples", "oranges"),
              c=c(12, 22, 22, 45, 67, 28), 
              d=c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday"),
              out = c(12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22),
              rate = c(-0.01, -0.02, 0.03, -0.04, 0.07, 0.06))

subData <- subset(data, (b == "apples" & rate < 0) | (b == "oranges" & rate > 0))
```

The code is pretty simple. It subsets `data` looking for your two constraints. In this code, `&` stands for `and` while `|` stands for `or`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter((b == "apples" & rate < 0) | (b == "oranges" & rate > 0))

  a       b  c       d out  rate
1 1  apples 12  Monday  12 -0.01
2 2  apples 45 Tuesday  18 -0.04
3 3 oranges 28 Tuesday  22  0.06
```